# How would I be able to get this line illusion soundwave art on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Hello, I was wondering if someone could help me out in replicating the line design like the one in this banner on Photoshop. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background is quite dark. It's good to lift the dark end with the curves tool to see better:

[image]

This is a complex composition that needs multiple layers and masks.

The background: I believe it's a real photo of a mat, towel or doormat, desaturated to BW

BUFTA logo: the characters separated, shifted to overlap, the A can be drawn (=easy), a little triangle is drawn

The "Soundwave" : It has a masked adjustment layer that makes it dark under the logo, but lets it be seen better at left and right.

The soundwave itself has 2 different versions. They are white and magenta. The magenta version is faded at left, probably with a manually drawn layer mask. Obviously the magenta version and the white wersion have the same bar pattern, because they seem to fit in the crossfade zone.

The magenta version is actually some texture pattern which has been masked by the white bars.

The bars: Probably made in Illustrator and taken to Photoshop. The regular spacing and the complex strokes are much easier in Illustrator.

The artist has taken his inspiration from a realtime spectrum display of an audio workstation. I have seen one that shows the powers in the separate frequency bands as discrete bars. The display had a persistence mode where the old content changed gradually to thinner and finally to small drops that faded. I do not believe that this is a screenshot, but the artist can well have had one when he planned what to do.

In Illustrator it's easy to make different pattern and art brushes. The bars have been at first equally long solid vertical lines that were got a brush pattern. Several different versioms have created and all vere taken to Photoshop as different layers.

It's possible, that finally with manually painted layer masks the artist made different brushings visible differently. I believe thar the strokes are shortened already in Illustrator to different lengths for different wave patterns, because it's very hard to make consistent top and bottom ends manually with layer masks in Photoshop.

Of course this all was a speculation, but this would be my way to create something in the same style, explained only in reverse order.

The following fast crunch is made with this receipe. It's awful, but it proves this receipe at least to be plausible.

Only easily available dashed lines are used as bars and the wave pattern envelopes were drawn by free hand in Photoshop. Perfect bar ends would need cutting as vectors in Illustrator

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! I appreciate this so much! Life saver :)

Comment: @Jennattran I'ts my pleasure! But cosider also to accept the answer or do an upvote.

Comment: Oh so sorry! I'm very new to this website! Apologies and I will follow up both now!